# HTAccess in PHPPennyAuction

Tags: .htaccess

I've just had a problem from last few hours. For a client I needed to redirect some urls to other specific urls through his .htaccess files. I just went through his ftp from Filezilla as he has cloud hosting, there wasn't any cpanel. I just had a .htaccess file which contains only 301 redirects, I uploaded it into /content folder.. Then I opened the site and saw it dead, before it it was working fine. Now whenever I open the site I receive this

```
Upgrade in progress.

    Copy changes to updated version(complete 4:45)
    Copy settings to updated version(complete 5:00)
    Back up whole site.(complete 6:44)
    Back up the database(complete 6:45)
    Upgrade database(complete 6:49)
    Upload new code
```

If I try to go to /index.php I receive this.

```
phpPennyAuction
phpPennyAuction is not yet completely installed.

Please check the following:

    That both of your .htaccess files are present and correct.
    That your server has mod_rewrite installed
    That your server is configured with AllowOverride set to All

If you need further assistance, please contact phpPennyAuction Support.
All contents © 2010 Scriptmatix Ltd. phpPennyAuction
```

Before just putting .htaccess file everything was fine. I just removed my .htaccess file, renamed the cache folder still the same problem. I might pay a little cup of coffee to anyone who helps fixing in this.

P.S Don't advise to ask on their forum, just contact their support the guy unofficially said "I'm not sure what's the problem I will charge 300 USD".

It is a big trouble for me, help appreciated.

Thanks
Kazim

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you uploaded the htaccess file you overwrote the htaccess file used by phpPennyAuction.

Try to find the original htaccess file(s) and put them back. They should be in the original "installer" or download.

After that you could put the content of your 301 file a the top of the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.htaccess` file that is provided in the folder:

`install-data/packages/01/phppa.zip/.htaccess`